# display info into tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js

I have a chart here :- [code link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jVmXPa?editors=0010)

Let me tell you what I am trying to achieve here.There are months of the year from the poly-lines -  January,February,March,.... Now when i hover over the months,I want to display week1,week2,....,week4 for January ,week5,week6,...,week8 for February and so on.That is,four weeks for each month I will use php to echo the value of the weekly data like - week1 :23,week2:45,week3:56 ,week4:75 etc.....

kindly help.

I tried to use a .csv file will all the 52 weeks info,but no luck.
JavaScript involved :

```js
'use strict';

var dataset = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];

// let colors = ['#8dd3c7', '#ffffb3', '#bebada', '#fb8072', '#80b1d3', '#fdb462', '#b3de69', '#fccde5', '#d9d9d9', '#bc80bd'];
let colors = ['#8dd3c7', '#ffffb3', '#bebada', '#fb8072', '#80b1d3', '#fdb462', '#b3de69', '#fccde5', '#d9d9d9', '#bc80bd', '#bc80bd', '#bc80bd'];
var weeks = ['January - 2016', 'February -2016', 'March - 2016', 'April - 2016', 'May - 2016', 'June - 2016', 'July - 2016', 'August - 2016', 'September - 2016', 'October - 2016', 'November - 2016', 'December - 2016'];

var width = document.querySelector('.chart-wrapper').offsetWidth,
  height = document.querySelector('.chart-wrapper').offsetHeight,
  minOfWH = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
  initialAnimDelay = 300,
  arcAnimDelay = 150,
  arcAnimDur = 3000,
  secDur = 1000,
  secIndividualdelay = 150;

var radius = undefined;

// calculate minimum of width and height to set chart radius
if (minOfWH > 200) {
  radius = 200;
} else {
  radius = minOfWH;
}

// append svg
var svg = d3.select('.chart-wrapper').append('svg').attr({
  'width': width,
  'height': height,
  'class': 'pieChart'
}).append('g');

svg.attr({
  'transform': 'translate(' + width / 2 + ', ' + height / 2 + ')'
});

// for drawing slices
var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(radius * 0.6).innerRadius(radius * 0.45);

// for labels and polylines
var outerArc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(radius * 0.85).outerRadius(radius * 0.85);

// d3 color generator
// let c10 = d3.scale.category10();

var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "tooltip").style("opacity", 0);

var pie = d3.layout.pie().value(function(d) {
  return d;
});

var draw = function draw() {

  svg.append("g").attr("class", "lines");
  svg.append("g").attr("class", "slices");
  svg.append("g").attr("class", "labels");

  // define slice
  var slice = svg.select('.slices').datum(dataset).selectAll('path').data(pie);
  slice.enter().append('path').attr({
    'fill': function fill(d, i) {
      return colors[i];
    },
    'd': arc,
    'stroke-width': '25px'
  }).attr('transform', function(d, i) {
    return 'rotate(-180, 0, 0)';
  }).style('opacity', 0).transition().delay(function(d, i) {
    return i * arcAnimDelay + initialAnimDelay;
  }).duration(arcAnimDur).ease('elastic').style('opacity', 1).attr('transform', 'rotate(0,0,0)');

  slice.transition().delay(function(d, i) {
    return arcAnimDur + i * secIndividualdelay;
  }).duration(secDur).attr('stroke-width', '5px');

  var midAngle = function midAngle(d) {
    return d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2;
  };

  var text = svg.select(".labels").selectAll("text").data(pie(dataset));

  text.enter().append('text').attr('dy', '0.35em').style("opacity", 0).attr("cursor", "default").style('fill', function(d, i) {
    return colors[i];
  }).text(function(d, i) {
    return weeks[i];
  }).attr('transform', function(d) {
    // calculate outerArc centroid for 'this' slice
    var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);
    // define left and right alignment of text labels
    pos[0] = radius * (midAngle(d) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
    return 'translate(' + pos + ')';
  }).style('text-anchor', function(d) {
    return midAngle(d) < Math.PI ? "start" : "end";
  }).transition().delay(function(d, i) {
    return arcAnimDur + i * secIndividualdelay;
  }).duration(secDur).style('opacity', 1);

  text.on("mousemove", function(d, i) {
    tooltip.html("the color here<br>is " + colors[i] + "<span style='color:" + colors[i] + ";'><br>This is a text in that color</span>").style('top', d3.event.pageY - 6 + 'px').style('left', d3.event.pageX + 14 + 'px').style("opacity", 1);
  }).on("mouseout", function(d) {
    tooltip.style("opacity", 0);
  });

  var polyline = svg.select(".lines").selectAll("polyline").data(pie(dataset));

  polyline.enter().append("polyline").style("opacity", 0.5).attr('points', function(d) {
    var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);
    pos[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midAngle(d) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
    return [arc.centroid(d), arc.centroid(d), arc.centroid(d)];
  }).transition().duration(secDur).delay(function(d, i) {
    return arcAnimDur + i * secIndividualdelay;
  }).attr('points', function(d) {
    var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);
    pos[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midAngle(d) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
    return [arc.centroid(d), outerArc.centroid(d), pos];
  });
};

draw();

var button = document.querySelector('button');

var replay = function replay() {

  d3.selectAll('.slices').transition().ease('back').duration(500).delay(0).style('opacity', 0).attr('transform', 'translate(0, 250)').remove();
  d3.selectAll('.lines').transition().ease('back').duration(500).delay(100).style('opacity', 0).attr('transform', 'translate(0, 250)').remove();
  d3.selectAll('.labels').transition().ease('back').duration(500).delay(200).style('opacity', 0).attr('transform', 'translate(0, 250)').remove();

  setTimeout(draw, 800);
};
```

Comment: So you want to display the weeks of that month when someone hovers over the month?

Comment: Thanks @Achilles . I want to display the weeks corresponding to every month.Lets say for january -week1 ,week2,week3,week4 .... for February week5 to week8 and so on for all the months.I will then use php to echo values such as        wee1-23 ("23,I will echo from the DB using php") .

Comment: You can try using JQuery since it's dynamic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [display popup/infotip/tooltip as hover a particular text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40716249/display-popup-infotip-tooltip-as-hover-a-particular-text)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the data- tag on each element to store the data and then use jQuery to read the data and push it to the tooltip. This is how I usually handle tooltip data since it can be dynamically updated on the element.

Example:

```
text.on("mouseover", function() {
   var tip = $(this).attr("data-tip");
   yourtooltip.text(tip);
});

<div class="text" data-tip="this is the data you want to display in your tooltip."></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input @Korgue .But In my case I dont think I will be able to use it.The text here is by using d3 .May be I am not able to get it.Will you be kind enough to edit the above codepen with what u r saying.May for a month or two,if u could show me .Anyways,I appreciate ur help.God bless.

Comment: tried using ur concept, unfortunately,no luck. @Korgrue