# jquery plugin to bind data to a tool-tip (poshy tip)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

In the below code ,I have a chart where I want to create a tooltip/infotip.

I have used jquery plugin (poshy tip :http://vadikom.com/demos/poshytip/#download)

Once I hover over the months,I would like to see the weeks.Like it is visible when u hover over "January" and "February" in the below code output.

Now the issue is how do I bind the tooltip to the months in the chart.

Kindly help.God bless.

```js
'use strict';

var dataset = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];

// let colors = ['#8dd3c7', '#ffffb3', '#bebada', '#fb8072', '#80b1d3', '#fdb462', '#b3de69', '#fccde5', '#d9d9d9', '#bc80bd'];
let colors = ['#67001f', '#b2182b', '#d6604d', '#f4a582', '#fddbc7', '#e0e0e0', '#bababa', '#878787', '#4d4d4d', '#1a1a1a', 'white', 'white'];
var months = ['January - 2016', 'February - 2016', 'March - 2016', 'April - 2016', 'May - 2016', 'June - 2016', 'July - 2016', 'August - 2016', 'September - 2016', 'October - 2016', 'November - 2016', 'December - 2016'];

var width = document.querySelector('.chart-wrapper').offsetWidth,
  height = document.querySelector('.chart-wrapper').offsetHeight,
  minOfWH = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
  initialAnimDelay = 300,
  arcAnimDelay = 150,
  arcAnimDur = 3000,
  secDur = 1000,
  secIndividualdelay = 150;

var radius = undefined;

// calculate minimum of width and height to set chart radius
if (minOfWH > 200) {
  radius = 200;
} else {
  radius = minOfWH;
}

// append svg
var svg = d3.select('.chart-wrapper').append('svg').attr({
  'width': width,
  'height': height,
  'class': 'pieChart'
}).append('g');

svg.attr({
  'transform': 'translate(' + width / 2 + ', ' + height / 2 + ')'
});

// for drawing slices
var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(radius * 0.6).innerRadius(radius * 0.45);

// for labels and polylines
var outerArc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(radius * 0.85).outerRadius(radius * 0.85);

// d3 color generator
// let c10 = d3.scale.category10();

var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "tooltip").style("opacity", 0);

var pie = d3.layout.pie().value(function(d) {
  return d;
});

var draw = function draw() {

  svg.append("g").attr("class", "lines");
  svg.append("g").attr("class", "slices");
  svg.append("g").attr("class", "labels");

  // define slice
  var slice = svg.select('.slices').datum(dataset).selectAll('path').data(pie);
  slice.enter().append('path').attr({
    'fill': function fill(d, i) {
      return colors[i];
    },
    'd': arc,
    'stroke-width': '25px'
  }).attr('transform', function(d, i) {
    return 'rotate(-180, 0, 0)';
  }).style('opacity', 0).transition().delay(function(d, i) {
    return i * arcAnimDelay + initialAnimDelay;
  }).duration(arcAnimDur).ease('elastic').style('opacity', 1).attr('transform', 'rotate(0,0,0)');

  slice.transition().delay(function(d, i) {
    return arcAnimDur + i * secIndividualdelay;
  }).duration(secDur).attr('stroke-width', '5px');

  var midAngle = function midAngle(d) {
    return d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2;
  };

  var text = svg.select(".labels").selectAll("text").data(pie(dataset));

  text.enter().append('text').attr('dy', '0.35em').style("opacity", 0).attr("cursor", "default").style('fill', function(d, i) {
    return colors[i];
  }).text(function(d, i) {
    return months[i];
  }).attr('transform', function(d) {
    // calculate outerArc centroid for 'this' slice
    var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);
    // define left and right alignment of text labels
    pos[0] = radius * (midAngle(d) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
    return 'translate(' + pos + ')';
  }).style('text-anchor', function(d) {
    return midAngle(d) < Math.PI ? "start" : "end";
  }).transition().delay(function(d, i) {
    return arcAnimDur + i * secIndividualdelay;
  }).duration(secDur).style('opacity', 1);


  var polyline = svg.select(".lines").selectAll("polyline").data(pie(dataset));

  polyline.enter().append("polyline").style("opacity", 0.5).attr('points', function(d) {
    var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);
    pos[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midAngle(d) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
    return [arc.centroid(d), arc.centroid(d), arc.centroid(d)];
  }).transition().duration(secDur).delay(function(d, i) {
    return arcAnimDur + i * secIndividualdelay;
  }).attr('points', function(d) {
    var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);
    pos[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midAngle(d) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
    return [arc.centroid(d), outerArc.centroid(d), pos];
  });
};

draw();

var button = document.querySelector('button');

var replay = function replay() {

  d3.selectAll('.slices').transition().ease('back').duration(500).delay(0).style('opacity', 0).attr('transform', 'translate(0, 250)').remove();
  d3.selectAll('.lines').transition().ease('back').duration(500).delay(100).style('opacity', 0).attr('transform', 'translate(0, 250)').remove();
  d3.selectAll('.labels').transition().ease('back').duration(500).delay(200).style('opacity', 0).attr('transform', 'translate(0, 250)').remove();

  setTimeout(draw, 800);
};
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.chart-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #0d0d0d;
  position: absolute;
}
path {
  stroke: #0d0d0d;
  /* stroke-width: 5px; */
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: fill 250ms;
  transition: fill 250ms;
}
path:hover {
  /* stroke-width: 10px; */
  fill: #fff;
}
text {
  font-size: .8em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
}
polyline {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-dasharray: 5px;
}
button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 820px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: .6em;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms;
  transition: all 250ms;
}
button:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #0d0d0d;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #fff;
}
button:active {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
div.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 4px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Crazy Pie Chart</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" />

  <!-- Tooltip classes -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://vadikom.com/demos/poshytip/src/tip-skyblue/tip-skyblue.css" type="text/css" />


  <!-- jQuery and the Poshy Tip plugin files -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://vadikom.com/demos/poshytip/src/jquery.poshytip.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

      $('.demo-tip-skyblue').poshytip({
        className: 'tip-skyblue',
        bgImageFrameSize: 9,
        offsetX: 0,
        offsetY: 20
      });
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="holder">
    <div id="content">
      <!-- #demo-tip-skyblue -->
      <p><a class="demo-tip-skyblue" title="<u>Weekly Information </u> <br> Week 1 - 45 <br> Week 2 - 56 <br> Week 3 - 67 <br> Week 4 - 77" href="#">January- 2016</a>
      </p>

      <p><a class="demo-tip-skyblue" title="<u>Weekly Information </u> <br> Week 1 - 1 <br> Week 2 - 5 <br> Week 3 - 6 <br> Week 4 - 7" href="#">February- 2016</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="chart-wrapper"></div>
  <button onclick='replay()'>Replay</button>
  <div class="textt" data-tip="this is the data ."></div>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js'></script>

  <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [display info into tooltip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40771906/display-info-into-tooltip)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a variable to store the data:

```
var dataWeeks = ["Week 1: 32<br>Week 2: 54<br>Week 3: 19<br>Week 4: 12",
    "Week 1: 22<br>Week 2: 14<br>Week 3: 12<br>Week 4: 03",
    "Week 1: 35<br>Week 2: 14<br>Week 3: 11<br>Week 4: 23",
    "Week 1: 65<br>Week 2: 53<br>Week 3: 16<br>Week 4: 11",
    //...
];
```

Each month's data is a single string. Then, using the code from my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40720100/5768908), show the data in the tooltip, using the `index` to select the month in `dataWeeks` (0 is January, 1 is February, 2 is March etc...):

```
text.on("mousemove", function(d, i) {
    tooltip.html(dataWeeks[i]);
    //...
```

Here is the demo:

```js
'use strict';

var dataset = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];

// let colors = ['#8dd3c7', '#ffffb3', '#bebada', '#fb8072', '#80b1d3', '#fdb462', '#b3de69', '#fccde5', '#d9d9d9', '#bc80bd'];
let colors = ['#67001f', '#b2182b', '#d6604d', '#f4a582', '#fddbc7', '#e0e0e0', '#bababa', '#878787', '#4d4d4d', '#1a1a1a', 'white', 'white'];
var months = ['January - 2016', 'February - 2016', 'March - 2016', 'April - 2016', 'May - 2016', 'June - 2016', 'July - 2016', 'August - 2016', 'September - 2016', 'October - 2016', 'November - 2016', 'December - 2016'];
var dataWeeks = ["Week 1: 32<br>Week 2: 54<br>Week 3: 19<br>Week 4: 12","Week 1: 22<br>Week 2: 14<br>Week 3: 12<br>Week 4: 03","Week 1: 35<br>Week 2: 14<br>Week 3: 11<br>Week 4: 23","Week 1: 65<br>Week 2: 53<br>Week 3: 16<br>Week 4: 11","Week 1: 11<br>Week 2: 52<br>Week 3: 22<br>Week 4: 12","Week 1: 09<br>Week 2: 44<br>Week 3: 59<br>Week 4: 87","Week 1: 42<br>Week 2: 76<br>Week 3: 69<br>Week 4: 33","Week 1: 11<br>Week 2: 65<br>Week 3: 69<br>Week 4: 33","Week 1: 99<br>Week 2: 66<br>Week 3: 19<br>Week 4: 84","Week 1: 16<br>Week 2: 66<br>Week 3: 11<br>Week 4: 86","Week 1: 21<br>Week 2: 52<br>Week 3: 12<br>Week 4: 37","Week 1: 90<br>Week 2: 69<br>Week 3: 19<br>Week 4: 17"];

var width = document.querySelector('.chart-wrapper').offsetWidth,
  height = document.querySelector('.chart-wrapper').offsetHeight,
  minOfWH = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
  initialAnimDelay = 300,
  arcAnimDelay = 150,
  arcAnimDur = 3000,
  secDur = 1000,
  secIndividualdelay = 150;

var radius = undefined;

// calculate minimum of width and height to set chart radius
if (minOfWH > 200) {
  radius = 200;
} else {
  radius = minOfWH;
}

// append svg
var svg = d3.select('.chart-wrapper').append('svg').attr({
  'width': width,
  'height': height,
  'class': 'pieChart'
}).append('g');

svg.attr({
  'transform': 'translate(' + width / 2 + ', ' + height / 2 + ')'
});

// for drawing slices
var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(radius * 0.6).innerRadius(radius * 0.45);

// for labels and polylines
var outerArc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(radius * 0.85).outerRadius(radius * 0.85);

// d3 color generator
// let c10 = d3.scale.category10();

var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "tooltip").style("opacity", 0);

var pie = d3.layout.pie().value(function(d) {
  return d;
});

var draw = function draw() {

  svg.append("g").attr("class", "lines");
  svg.append("g").attr("class", "slices");
  svg.append("g").attr("class", "labels");

  // define slice
  var slice = svg.select('.slices').datum(dataset).selectAll('path').data(pie);
  slice.enter().append('path').attr({
    'fill': function fill(d, i) {
      return colors[i];
    },
    'd': arc,
    'stroke-width': '25px'
  }).attr('transform', function(d, i) {
    return 'rotate(-180, 0, 0)';
  }).style('opacity', 0).transition().delay(function(d, i) {
    return i * arcAnimDelay + initialAnimDelay;
  }).duration(arcAnimDur).ease('elastic').style('opacity', 1).attr('transform', 'rotate(0,0,0)');

  slice.transition().delay(function(d, i) {
    return arcAnimDur + i * secIndividualdelay;
  }).duration(secDur).attr('stroke-width', '5px');

  var midAngle = function midAngle(d) {
    return d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2;
  };

  var text = svg.select(".labels").selectAll("text").data(pie(dataset));

  text.enter().append('text').attr('dy', '0.35em').style("opacity", 0).attr("cursor", "default").style('fill', function(d, i) {
    return colors[i];
  }).text(function(d, i) {
    return months[i];
  }).attr('transform', function(d) {
    // calculate outerArc centroid for 'this' slice
    var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);
    // define left and right alignment of text labels
    pos[0] = radius * (midAngle(d) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
    return 'translate(' + pos + ')';
  }).style('text-anchor', function(d) {
    return midAngle(d) < Math.PI ? "start" : "end";
  }).transition().delay(function(d, i) {
    return arcAnimDur + i * secIndividualdelay;
  }).duration(secDur).style('opacity', 1);
  
   text.on("mousemove", function(d, i) {
                tooltip.html(dataWeeks[i])
                        .style('top', d3.event.pageY - 6 + 'px')
                        .style('left', d3.event.pageX + 14 + 'px')
                        .style("opacity", 1);
            }).on("mouseout", function(d) {
                tooltip.style("opacity", 0);
            });


  var polyline = svg.select(".lines").selectAll("polyline").data(pie(dataset));

  polyline.enter().append("polyline").style("opacity", 0.5).attr('points', function(d) {
    var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);
    pos[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midAngle(d) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
    return [arc.centroid(d), arc.centroid(d), arc.centroid(d)];
  }).transition().duration(secDur).delay(function(d, i) {
    return arcAnimDur + i * secIndividualdelay;
  }).attr('points', function(d) {
    var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);
    pos[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midAngle(d) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
    return [arc.centroid(d), outerArc.centroid(d), pos];
  });
};

draw();

var button = document.querySelector('button');

var replay = function replay() {

  d3.selectAll('.slices').transition().ease('back').duration(500).delay(0).style('opacity', 0).attr('transform', 'translate(0, 250)').remove();
  d3.selectAll('.lines').transition().ease('back').duration(500).delay(100).style('opacity', 0).attr('transform', 'translate(0, 250)').remove();
  d3.selectAll('.labels').transition().ease('back').duration(500).delay(200).style('opacity', 0).attr('transform', 'translate(0, 250)').remove();

  setTimeout(draw, 800);
};
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.chart-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #0d0d0d;
  position: absolute;
}
path {
  stroke: #0d0d0d;
  /* stroke-width: 5px; */
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: fill 250ms;
  transition: fill 250ms;
}
path:hover {
  /* stroke-width: 10px; */
  fill: #fff;
}
text {
  font-size: .8em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
}
polyline {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-dasharray: 5px;
}
button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 820px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: .6em;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms;
  transition: all 250ms;
}
button:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #0d0d0d;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #fff;
}
button:active {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
div.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 4px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Crazy Pie Chart</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" />

  <!-- Tooltip classes -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://vadikom.com/demos/poshytip/src/tip-skyblue/tip-skyblue.css" type="text/css" />


 

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


</head>

<body>

 


  <div class="chart-wrapper"></div>
  <button onclick='replay()'>Replay</button>
  <div class="textt" data-tip="this is the data ."></div>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js'></script>

  <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```